App Center Crashing in 24.04 fresh install
I am running a fresh install of 24.04 on VirtualBox 6.1.50_Ubuntu r161033 (with a Ubuntu 22.04 host).  App Center opens to a white screen and immediately closes.
Below is a screenshot of the relevant portion of the syslog.


Try sudo snap refresh. Does it help?

Same problem in new install of ubuntu 24.04 on my PC. sudo snap refresh not helping

Tried sudo snap refresh as suggested, did not fix the problem.

Accordin to what i read and having recently issues running 24.04 on VM and disableing 3D accelereation i also tried that here...
So Settings > Apps > App Center > disable opengl.
For me it now opens.

I can confirm that disabling OpenGL in App Center settings works for me.  It also works for Firmware Updater if you disable OpenGL for it.

I had the same problem.  For unrelated reasons, I changed the windowing system from Wayland to X11.  Then, I launched snap-store from the terminal to see and error messages.  Here is what I got:
 ~$ snap-store
Gtk-Message: 11:55:34.391: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.

(snap-store:8363): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:55:34.640: GTK+ module /snap/snap-store/1134/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 11:55:34.640: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

(snap-store:8363): Gtk-WARNING **: 11:55:34.650: GTK+ module /snap/snap-store/1134/gnome-platform/usr/lib/gtk-2.0/modules/libcanberra-gtk-module.so cannot be loaded.
GTK+ 2.x symbols detected. Using GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3 in the same process is not supported.
Gtk-Message: 11:55:34.650: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
flutter: INFO snap-store: Logging to /home/diomass/snap/snap-store/1134/.local/share/snap-store/snap-store.log

After that though, the App Center did launch and work.

I had also discovered that if I switched to X11 the Snap Store works.  I did not get the errors that you got, but I did get an unrelated system error on the system journal on first login after switching.  Otherwise it seems to be working, but I don't think the Ubuntu team would call "Don't use Wayland" a fix.

The original issue also affected Firmware Updater, and that is also fixed by using X11.  It was suggested that I file a bug report on this, Robert Prince had already done so, I added my info.  You can see it at https://github.com/ubuntu/app-center/issues/1655#issuecomment-2086861832

THIS WORKED FOR ME! THANK YOU!
According to what i read and having recently issues running 24.04 on VM and disabling 3D acceleration i also tried that here...
**So Settings > Apps > App Center > disable opengl **

duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/a/1512569/

For my New 24.04 this works for me

**So Settings > Apps > App Center > disable opengl **

