App Center crashes every time i open it fresh install 24.04 LTS
guys can anyone help me with this:
snap-store
Gtk-Message: 14:15:02.590: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
flutter: INFO snap-store: Logging to /home/andre-dias/snap/snap-store/1173/.local/share/snap-store/snap-store.log
No provider of glFenceSync found.  Requires one of:
    Desktop OpenGL 3.2
    GL_ARB_sync
    OpenGL ES 3.0
    GL_APPLE_sync
Aborted (core dumped)


in terminal run sudo snap refresh and edit your question with the results, do not add it in the comment.

Followed the disable OpenGL fix here successfully: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1511937/app-center-crashing-in-24-04-fresh-install
